# Regular Expression with nested "["

Tags: python, regex

I am familiar with Regular Expressions, but this complex example is tripping me up. I trying to understand what this line of code is doing:

```
r'/(\\.|[^[/\\\n]|\[(\\.|[^\]\\\n])*])+/([gim]+\b|\B)'
```

It is a code snippet that is trying to detect a regular expression, for example: `/\s+/`. I understand it until the nested `[`, `\[`, and the `(` counterparts.

(I need to port this code from Python to Java and am having problems understanding how the above works, and why it does not work as is in Java.)

Comment: If you port this to Java's `Pattern.compile("...")` then you'll have to double every `\ ` as strings in Java treat `\ ` as an escape for the following character and you need the `compile()` method to see exactly what you have shown here.

Comment: @AdrianPronk - Yeah, I have done that. See here for more details on the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492180/differences-in-regex-syntax-between-python-and-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an exploded version that might help:

```
/                      # Match an opening slash
(                      # Followed by one or more...
  \\.                  #    Backslash followed by any character
  |                    #   or...
  [^[/\\\n]            #    Something that's not a [, /, \, or newline
  |                    #   or...
  \[                   #    A literal [, followed by any number of...
    (
      \\.              #     backslashes followed by any character
      |                #     or...
      [^\]\\\n]        #     something that's not a ], \, or newline
    )*
  ]                    #    and ending with a ]
)+
/                      # And a closing slash
(
  [gim]+\b             # Followed by one or more of g, i, m
  |
  \B                   # or something that isn't a word boundary
)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `[^[/\\\n]` is doing?

Comment: It looks like it is matching any character that is not a left bracket, forward slash, backslash, or newline. I'm not sure if it is valid to not escape the left bracket, but I guess it's not really ambiguous.

Comment: @Vineet added in explanations for each part.

Comment: In `[^[/\\\n]` - why does the second `[` not go into the next line? And why does that not effect the `]`? Sorry, for so many questions...

Comment: Because once you're in a character class (in a `[]`), another `[` is treated as one of the characters included in the character class - sort of like how a `-`, if at the end of a character class, doesn't need to be escaped. so for instance, `[^[]` is "any character that is not a `[`."

Comment: Thanks for your help. A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492180/differences-in-regex-syntax-between-python-and-java

Comment: So, spent more time looking into this. It seems that in *Python* some characters don't need to be escaped (like the nested `[`), but that in *Java* they do need to be escaped.