# java regex flavor in python

Tags: java, python, regex

I am python programmer and always played regular expressions in python but recently I have been asked to use java flavor regular expression, does mean I have to write application in java. So just checking is there a way to use java regex in python? Thanks

Comment: Regex does differ a bit across languages, but the core functions remain the same. For more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/10492382/4983469

Comment: Thanks for the checking. Yes I know different across the languages but how do I get java flavor in python?

Comment: check the link.

Comment: No point of adding negative mark on a valid question. I have already looked at the link and it does not work for my regex. Example I have look behind regex `(?:(?<!.?[-:0-9\/] ?)`
the optional . and space does not work in python

Comment: No, not easily or directly.  What would be the point?  Can you speak Spanish in English?  Maybe I am missing the point.

Comment: The link which clearly the OP has not read fully does not talk abt any specific regex but rather on how regex differes between java and python. I linked it so u can get an idea on what changes u need to do to change a regex wrten in python to work in java. Beyond this, i dont know what cna help u.. The question is nto valid in my opinion. Hence the downvote

Comment: @Andrew If can do in python then I can run existing application otherwise I have to re-write whole application in Java. I am playing with writing regex part in Java and invoking that in python so will post here on my experiment.

Comment: @Spark Scala Developer OK, I understand.  Sounds messy.  I'll look forward to the post.  Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew, Found a way using py4j.
Example is here: https://www.py4j.org 
Basically need to run small java program which starts gateway server and then using py4j can access the java methods in python.

Tried with my existing python application and it works. It saved quite a lot of time i.e. do not have to develop whole application in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.py4j.org

Below java program need to be run first

```
import py4j.GatewayServer;

public class AdditionApplication {

  public int addition(int first, int second) {
    return first + second;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AdditionApplication app = new AdditionApplication();
    // app is now the gateway.entry_point
    GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(app);
    server.start();
  }
}
```

Below is the way to access java addition method in python

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()
gateway.entry_point.addition(10, 10)
```

Comment: Per, https://www.py4j.org, the port #s used are 25332-25334, but per https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=128, those port # are unassigned.

Comment: They may not be but default ports. These ports can be changed
https://www.py4j.org/py4j_java_gateway.html#module-py4j.java_gateway